# Synchronize I/O with calling thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

In [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810438.aspx), section 'More Waiting...', when author talked about synchronize i/o with thread, the 1st example he gives is:

```
hFile = CreateFile(....,FILE_IO_OVERLAPPED,...);
ReadFile(hFile,...)
< Do some computation.>
WaitForSingleObject(hFile,INFINITE);
```

I had the impression that both 'CreateFile' and 'ReadFile' are **synchronous** APIs, no? Why would a 'WaitForSingleObject' needed here? Wouldn't 'CreateFile' and 'ReadFile' block until the operation is over and then return?

Then some more confusion coming when author talks about 'alertable waiting'. What is it, a thread state after WaitForSingleObjectEx()? then why author give:

```
while (WaitForSingleObject(hObject,TRUE)==WAIT_IO_COMPLETION);
```

as example instead of

```
while (WaitForSingleObjectEx(hObject,TRUE)==WAIT_IO_COMPLETION);
```

?

and should 'ex' functions be together like:

```
hFile = CreateFile(....,FILE_IO_OVERLAPPED,...);
ReadFileEx(hFile,...)
< Do some computation.>
while (WaitForSingleObjectEx(hObject,TRUE)==WAIT_IO_COMPLETION);
```

Any one can explain a little more?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document also states following:

> Asynchronous I/O is a way the operating system provides for letting
>   I/O instructions execute in the background, the idea being roughly
>   that a call to ReadFile or WriteFile will return immediately to the
>   caller and overlap the I/O operation itself with the computation of
>   the thread that called it in the first place. This technique only
>   works for I/O devices whose drivers support asynchronous I/O and
>   manifests itself to the programmer through the flag FILE_IO_OVERLAPPED <sup>(*)</sup>
>   that can be passed to the CreateFile call. I/O performed on such a
>   file object will behave quite differently from synchronous I/O.

The methods are synchronous/asynchronous depending on parameters passed to CreateFile

<sup>* <sub>should read FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks Yossarian. I am being too careless on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you quoted the code, but apparently didn't read it :-) "Overlapped IO" is async.

As for alertable waits, I don't think they are used all that often.

Comment: dumb i am :( as to miss the 'FILE_IO_OVERLAPPED'. Thanks Christian.

Answer (score 2):

Those are quite a lot of questions.

> I had the impression that both 'CreateFile' and 'ReadFile' are synchronous APIs, no?

Both is true. It depends on the parameter you pass to the Create/Read FileFunction.
You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A short excerp:

> ... If hFile is opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, it is an asynchronous file handle; otherwise it is synchronous....

For your second Question I guess the `WaitForSingleObject` is just wrong it should be `WaitForSingleObjectEx`

If you use the Ex version of a function or not depends if you need the additional functionality of the Ex version or not. Although I consider it as bad style if you mix them in your code.

Comment: None of the `WaitFor...()` functions support a file handle as input.  For overlapped I/O, you have to use an `OVERLAPPED` structure with a waitable event via `CreateEvent()` instead, then you can wait on the event, not the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) for `ReadFile()`:

> This function is designed for both synchronous and asynchronous operations.

`ReadFile()` is asynchronous if `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` was passed to `CreateFile()` and an `OVERLAPPED` structure is passed to `ReadFile()`, eg:

```
hFile = CreateFile(..., FILE_IO_OVERLAPPED, ...); 
...
OVERLAPPED ol = {0};
ol.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (!ReadFile(hFile, ..., &ol))
{
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
    {
        // error... 
    }
}
...
WaitForSingleObject(ol.hEvent, INFINITE); // or GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ol, ..., TRUE);
```